# Save each element of a list to a file, using file names from other df

Tags: r, list

I have a dataframe like this:

```
df<-structure(list(PCL_ATTACHMENT_ID = c(1, 2, 3), PROTOCOL_ID = c(190, 
190, 190), FILE_NAME = c("Recruitment Flyer Version 2.0.pdf", 
"Protocol - Sabc.pdf", "Consent- Sabc .pdf"
), MODIFIED_DATE = structure(c(1598377719, 1520781558, 1520781566
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "")), row.names = c(NA, 
3L), class = "data.frame")
```

And, separately, using information from that dataframe, I've downloaded the raw binary files of the pdfs mentioned in each row from an oracle database.  They are stored in a list called "listraws" like so:
[image]

I know that if I wanted to save one of those binary files as a pdf, I could do this:

```
writeBin(listraws[[2]], "Doc I downloaded2.pdf")
```

but then I'd have to supply the name and file format individually to each file, they may not all be pdfs.

What I'd like to do is loop through the list, save each file as its 'original' name listed in the dataframe, and append the protocol ID at the beginning.

Example:

The first element of the list (pcl_attachment_id 1 in the df) would be titled "190 - Recruitment Flyer Version 2.0.pdf"

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
for (i in seq_along(listraws)) {
  writeBin(listraws[[i]], df$FILE_NAME[i])
}
```

or

```r
ign <- Map(writeBin, listraws, df$FILE_NAME)`
```

(`ign` will be a `list`, likely with `NULL`s.)

If you need to include `df$PROTOCOL_ID` in your filename, just handle that externally, such as

```r
Map(writeBin, listraws,
    with(df, sprintf("%s - %s", PROTOCOL_ID, FILE_NAME)))
```

Comment: Worked beautifully